# ¿Tienes a alguien que quisieras que se anime a entrar a la carrera para ser moderador del sitio?

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

Este espacio lo dejamos para que los que quisieran nominar a alguien para ser moderador tengan la oportunidad de comunicar sus razones. Recuerden que en las elecciones las nominaciones las deberá hacer el candidato interesado (esto es, un usuario solo puede nominarse a sí mismo). Pueden leer [más sobre el proceso aquí](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/).

Este hilo es solamente para mencionar a la gente que piensan que haría un buen trabajo como moderador y para dar las razones por ello.

**Este espacio no es para postularse todavía.**

Las fechas para cuando vamos a empezar están [publicadas en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/), pueden ver allí los detalles del proceso.

¡Hablemos entonces! ¿Quién sería buen moderador para el sitio y por qué?

Comment: ¿Qué moderadores se quedarán y cuáles serán renovados? Supongo que Luiggi se queda, pero si no, yo lo nominaría

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Empezaríamos desde cero - todos los moderadores activos tendrían que postularse. La comunidad escogerá a los 3 nuevos.

Answer (score 19):

Bajo mi punto de vista basandome en el tiempo que llevo en SOes, pienso que [**Alvaro Montoro**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) podria realizar muy bien las labores de moderacion.

[image: Flxter]

---

El cuenta con larga experiencia en la red Exchange y lo mas importante en esta parte de la red que es SOes.

Alvaro ha estado desde prácticamente el inicio del sitio, estando presente en todo momento hasta la actualidad, una cosa a valorar pues trasmite constancia y compromiso, ademas al haber visto crecer el sito puede tener con ello una vision mas amplia de hacia donde se dirige el sitio, sumado a una percepción mas estable en cuanto a lo que se puede mejorar en el lugar, así como las cosas que han mejorado, o aquellas en las que aun falta algo mas de trabajo, pudiendo discriminar cuales son mas importantes o prioritarias.

Comment: Disculpame la edición. Solo para corregir algún pequeño error ortográfico

Comment: @Pikoh nada que disculpar, si acaso agredecerle que lo hicieras, gracias. Saludos

Comment: Muy buena sugerencia, creo que Alvaro sería un excelente moderador.

Answer (score 19):

Yo nominaría a [fredyfx](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx):

[image: fredyfx]

Él es un miembro activo de la comunidad, y no sólo de StackOverflow (donde se mueve principalmente por las tecnologías Microsoft y C#), sino también fuera del sitio, donde colabora en diferentes proyectos de .Net. Tiene experiencia como moderador *pro tempore* y es un usuario que está ahí cuando se le necesita, con respuestas moderadas (sin juego de palabras) y buenas publicaciones.

Comment: gracias hermano :D

Comment: Maestro @fredyfx si te llegas a postular, cuenta con mi voto :D

Answer (score 18):

Sin duda me gustaría que sea [**fedorqui**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui)

[image: fedorqui]

Aporta mucho a la comunidad, es leal y un usuario bastante experimentado en la red [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=accounts).

- [Moderador en Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui)

Comment: Moderador más experimentado que esté activo en SOes no vamos a encontrar.

Comment: No se si una persona pueda ser moderador de varias comunidades, pero ha quedado claro que el simpre quiere ayudar a los miembros de la comunidad y es una apuesta segura

Comment: @jasilva - Si.. se puede ser moderador en varias comunidades :)

Comment: apuesto por Lord Fedorqui :D

Comment: Coincido totalmente, ¡qué mejor que alguien que conoce la comunidad y cuenta con la experiencia mas que necesaria! Esperemos ver a Fedorqui con su diamante en [es.so] :D

Comment: De hecho [hay quien es moderador de cinco comunidades](https://stackexchange.com/users/505925/monica-cellio?tab=accounts)... ¡e [incluso de siete](https://stackexchange.com/users/251740/rory-alsop?tab=accounts)!

Comment: Muchas gracias por sugerir mi nombre aldanux, es un honor. En principio no cuento con presentarme: los próximos meses van a estar bastante cargaditos en el ámbito familiar (con nueva _release_ :D) y con algún nuevo trabajo puntual que me quitará bastante tiempo. Dado que ya actualmente tampoco dispongo de mucho tiempo, me gusta ir colaborando puntualmente en colas de revisión, debatir en Meta, etc. sin la necesidad de tener que acordar posturas con un grupo de gente ni comprometerme a estar siempre disponible.

Comment: @fedorqui - Enhorabuena por el nuevo "release"... :) quizás te hubiese tenido que preguntar antes... pero cómo ves tienes una gran aceptación de la comunidad ;)... en fin.. no hay que ser moderador para poder apoyar y colaborar ... suerte en tu futuro camino!

Answer (score 11):

Suscribo muchas de las nominaciones: creo que podemos estar contentos de disponer de buen banquillo. De entre ellas, creo que [**lois6b**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) puede ser una buena adición.

[image: lois6b]

Además de ser el editor más rápido del oeste, tiene una virtud esencial: el sentido común. La gente con experiencia nos puede enseñar cómo transitar por caminos conocidos; la que tiene sentido común nos puede plantear otros que pueden llevarnos más lejos.

También contribuye activamente en el chat y está en el lado este del Atlántico y por tanto en una franja horaria poco representada actualmente.

Comment: Apoyo la moción, todo un loquillo ese lois, de igual forma sería genial tenerlo con su diamante :)

Comment: Todo mi apoyo :)

Comment: ostras fedorqui, me halagas :D

Answer (score 9):

Solicito a [**Flxtr**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr) a que se postule.

[image: Flxter]

Es un profesional de las tecnologías de información de los que más participa en el sitio principal, en Meta y en el chat. Flxtr es "echado para delante", prueba de ello es que le invité a juntos organizáramos el primer encuentro de fans de Stack Overflow en español en Monterrey, México, e inmediatamente dijo que sí, siendo que nunca antes había participado en la coordinación de un evento similar. Esto me dio la oportunidad de conocerlo en persona e interactuar con él a través de otros espacios.

Por lo anterior confio plenamente en que realizará un excelente papel como moderador ♦.

Comment: ¡Hombre! Qué gran gesto de tu parte. Muchas gracias por haber pensado en mí :) ya también voté por ti ya que considero totalmente que tienes madera de moderador :D

Answer (score 8):

Otra nominación: [Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza)

[image: Luiggi Mendoza]

Luiggi es el moderador que lleva más tiempo en activo (si no contamos a [Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman), que "pasó a mejor vida" :P) y conoce los entresijos de la moderación. Alguna vez en el pasado he podido estar en desacuerdo con alguna decisión que ha tomado, pero debo reconocer que es eficiente, justo y correcto como el que más, y sus acciones siempre están justificadas y tienen una explicación lógica detrás.

Si se presenta, tendrá mi voto.

Comment: ¡Y mi voto también!

Answer (score 6):

Estaba pensando en *@Mariano*, pero ahora recordé que él no quería ser moderador, debido a la gran responsabilidad y también a estar más lejos de la cola de revisiones, así que lamentablemente no es posible.

En vez de eso, sería bastante bueno que esté [**Rubén**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%C3%A9n) como moderador del sitio.

[image: Rubén]

En estos últimos tiempos estuvo muy ocupado aportando en el *FAQ*. Pienso que él tiene como objetivo que el sitio sea de calidad. Además me pareció bueno con la cuestión de las etiquetas.

Comment: Yo también estaba pensando en Mariano :)

Comment: Rubén sería un buen candidato. Pero si piensa presentarse debiera pedir a Juan Garza que quite su nombre del blog en que se anuncian las elecciones. Se que no hay mala intención por parte de nadie pero el gestor de comunidad debiera mantener apariencia de imparcialidad.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos No te preocupes, no pienso participar en la carrera de este año por las clases que impatiré el próximo semestre, otros compromisos, entre otras cosas.

Comment: el hermano Rubén siempre le anda con todo el power!! sus aportes crecen con la comunidad, en especial siento que logra hacer integración de la hermandad con sus publicaciones en META. Voto por él también :D

Comment: @Rubén ¿Quién es ese tal Mariano?

Comment: @PaulVargas Vaya, pensé que no te íbamos a leer por aquí. En cuanto a Mariano, como no quiere ser moderador electo, te contaré luego de las elecciones ;)

Answer (score 4):

Animo a [**ArtEze**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) a que se presente.

[image: ArtEze]

Es una persona activa y proactiva, que es algo que se necesita mucho en este sitio.
Pero actúa para habilitar a la comunidad a desarrollarse y menos para promover su propia agenda.
En tiempos estaba verde en el funcionamiento del sito pero tras el tiempo que ha estado como pro-tempore esto se ha solucionado.

Comment: un recurso imprescindible. +1 al eze.

Comment: Por los comentarios que leí en el [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/?cb=1) sobre las elecciones, doy mi opinón. Creo que Arteze empezó flojo pero poco a poco va mejorando. Lo que se puede esperar de cualquiera. Nadie nace aprendido y aunque conozcas como funciona el sitio, la moderación no es tan fácil. Sin embargo su perfil revela sus ganas de mejorar el sitio con muchas medallas asociadas a la moderación y eso es lo importante. Las ganas de cambiar algo para mejor. El tiempo y la experiencia le hará mejor moderador.

Comment: @lois6b te doy la razón, nadie nace aprendido y ArtEze va mejorando poco a poco y si continúa -que visto el apoyo que tiene, continuará- hará un buen trabajo... pero debe cambiar bastantes cosas para ello.

Comment: Ya sabemos cómo se maneja @ArtEze, sin duda alguna ha hecho un excelente trabajo como moderador pro tempore, cuenta con mi voto :D

Answer (score -10):

Creo que olvidaron a [**Miquel Coll**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll)

[image: Miquel Coll]

A mi parecer ha tenido una participación excelente como moderador

Ha sabido aplicar justicia, corregir y corregirse a él mismo.

Comment: Desde hace tiempo ya no esta más activo en SO* .... :/

Comment: Sin desmerecer todo el buen trabajo que hizo, creo que dejar de participar como moderador pone en un brete al resto del equipo (a Luiggi en concreto, pues para entonces estaba él solo). Probablemente debería haber gestionado la situación de una forma más constructiva para él y la comunidad, desacelerando su participación al punto en que sí viera que le era posible compaginarlo con su día a día. Moderar desgasta y no da demasiadas alegrías.