# ¿Tienes a alguien que quisieras que se anime a entrar a la carrera para ser moderador del sitio? Elecciones 2019

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

Recordando la publicación de JuanM de 2017 [¿Tienes a alguien que quisieras que se anime a entrar a la carrera para ser moderador del sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2298/tienes-a-alguien-que-quisieras-que-se-anime-a-entrar-a-la-carrera-para-ser-mode), me gustaría volver a plantear la pregunta.

Recuerdo que:

> Este hilo es solamente para mencionar a la gente que piensan que haría un buen trabajo como moderador y para dar las razones por ello.
>
> Este espacio no es para postularse todavía.

Esta publicación puede ser importante para aquellas personas que dudan en si presentarse o no.

Cuando me presenté tenía decidido hacerlo pero sin duda ver que alguien más quería que así fuera reafirmó mi decisión y me sentí más confiado.

**¿Quién sería buen moderador para el sitio y por qué?**

Answer (score 20):

Por mi parte, me gustaría ver presentarse a [Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh)

[image: perfil para Pikoh en Stack Overflow en español, Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la informática]

Es un usuario que lleva mucho tiempo en el sitio, participa todos los días, lanza muchos reportes útiles, tiene la impresionante cifra de más de 4.000 revisiones de colas, y también responde mucho en Meta.

Se preocupa por el sitio y la calidad del mismo, así como de ayudar a usuarios.

Tiene buenos razonamientos, mente fría y es paciente hasta con las conductas más repetitivas (cosa que siendo mod, necesitas ser).

Sé que ser moderador [es algo que se ha planteado mínimamente](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49599762#49599762) así que, dad upvote los que compartan mi opinión y ganas de Pikoh <strike>for president</strike> para mod!

<sub>además, está en la franja horaria española, lo cual vendría estupendamente para apoyar mi *turno*</sub>

Comment: Si el se presenta y participa cuenta con mi voto

Comment: Me parece que es una excelente opción, @Pikoh tiene todas las cualidades

Answer (score 11):

A mi me gustaría proponer a Gonzalo, ya que tiene mucho conocimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pense q era Gonzalo

Comment: @ManucoBianco Así gracias

Comment: Gracias chicos por proponerlo.. El problema es que la mayor parte del acto eleccionario no voy a estar disponible... salvo por contados momentos. Aunque me gustaria ver un moderador en un turno intermedio. No lo descarto, pero no se si no se vera mal que la mayor parte del tiempo ni aparezca...

Comment: También le apoyaría!

Answer (score 6):

Ahora que lo preguntas...si. Tengo un par de candidatos que me gustaría que se presentaran.

1. [Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano)

[image: Pablo Lozano]

Creo que sería un moderador estupendo, dada su experiencia y sentido común. El sitio se beneficiaría mucho contando con el.

2. [fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui)

[image: fedorqui]

Creo que poco hay que decir aqui. Tiene experiencia como moderador, y todos conocemos su dedicación al sitio sobre todo en Meta. ¿Que haríamos sin sus ediciones y su cuidado de las etiquetas? Aunque en las anteriores elecciones comentó que no quería presentarse, yo ahí dejo mi sugerencia a ver si se lo piensa... :)

---

En esta lista no están todos los que son, pero si son todos los que están. Espero que se presenten y contarán con mi voto.

Comment: había que intentarlo... xD

Comment: Una lástima @fedorqui, pero como dice lois había que intentarlo :)