# Dejo mi puesto de moderador diamantado

Tags: discusión

Lo primero, **muchas gracias a todos** por vuestro apoyo en las acciones de moderación y por vuestro apoyo personal en el chat. Agradecer, claro, a los que me votasteis. Y a mis compañeros diamantados, por supuesto.

Hace tiempo que estoy inactivo por varios motivos. Hubo problemas en la comunidad que no se manejaron ni se resolvieron como pienso que deberían y  cambios en la organizacion con efectos desastrosos, dejando todo un resultado bastante deplorable. Además del desgaste natural con el tiempo y esfuerzo.

Cuando empecé en el sitio, a parte de subir reputación, quería ayudar al propio sitio. Por eso me presenté a moderador diamantado. Creía que el esfuerzo de todos haría que el sitio creciera y destacara sobre el resto de sitios en la red. Por un tiempo creí eso.

Dado que la organización está haciendo cambios que ellos quieren y no lo que la comunidad quiere o respalda, creo que va a ser muy dificil convertir los sitios de SE en el lugar que los propios usuarios queremos que sea, donde nos sintamos a gusto participando.

¿Cómo vamos a esforzarnos en mantener a flote una plataforma cuando vemos que no se nos escucha y valora?

Independientemente de estos problemas, la moderación es muy poco gratificante. He tenido algunas situaciones en las que estoy verdaderamente orgulloso de mi ayuda y dedicación. Pero por cada usuario agradecido de mi ayuda, hay varios que se quejan de mis acciones. Esto sin duda no es determinante pero todo suma y me afecta.

No se, no soy bueno en este tipo de escritos.

Pero dejar de ser moderador no es algo malo. Aunque ahora estoy algo cansado, de momento no dejaré de participar en el sitio. Quizá haya otras elecciones y gente con más ganas que las mias actuales pueda obtener el diamante y ayudar.

Muchas gracias de nuevo. Ha sido una oportunidad increíble.

Comment: **F** ... Ahora fuera de bromas, gracias a ti por la moderación, y la ayuda que has ofrecido y sobretodo la paciencia que has demostrado en el chat. Totalmente comprensibles tus motivos...

Comment: Espero que todo vaya bien en tu vida, te lo mereces, y espero que vuelvas aunque solo sea por hablar y comentar banalidades diarias.
Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por vuestros mensajes. Si, seguiré por aqui de momento

Comment: Es una gran pena. Muchas gracias por un excelente trabajo. <3

Comment: A diferencia de otros moderadores que renunciaron a su puesto a ti pude conocerte.. asi que se directamente la perdida que supone para la comunidad.. gracias por las ayudas que me dabas en el chat con el javascript ;) siempre estabas por ahi disponible para ayudar, te estoy agradecido... Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias @RazerJs . Por el chat seguiré dandole al js y regex hehe

Comment: @lois6b Pese a lo que digan algunos al respecto (lo cual indica su ignorancia), `regex` es genial.

Comment: Pues yo acabo de llegar a SO... Ni si quiera sabía que eras moderador; lo que sí sé es que, cuando me he pasado por el chat, me has hecho sentir como en casa desde el primer día. Gracias.

Comment: @GuardabosqueS no lo sabias? buenisimo XD   pues si... Me alegra que te sintieras a gusto en el chat. Un saludo, vecino!

Comment: Algo intuía, pero no me fijo en esas cosas, porque considero que el cargo no es reflejo de las personas (en general, aunque es cierto que aquí, en SO, a moderador no llegará ningún zotes). Ya sabes lo que dicen: cuando una puerta se cierra otra se abre... Te deseo lo mejor en tu próxima andadura. ¡Un fuerte abrazo, vecino!

Answer (score 26):

Aunque este anuncio era algo que ya me esperaba, no hace que el impacto sea menor.

Lamento muchísimo perderte como moderador, creo que has sido tremendamente útil al sitio, dialogante y equitativo en tus acciones, y un excelente compañero.

Para mi quedarán siempre situaciones en la que defendiste a usuarios del sitio (y a mi mismo) contra actitudes que distaban mucho de ser constructivas (en mi opinión) con uñas y dientes. Siempre te estaré agradecido por ello.

Es un día triste para el sitio, o al menos para mi, aunque entiendo perfectamente las razones que te han llevado a tomar esta decisión. Te deseo lo mejor y personalmente, aquí me tienes para lo que necesites.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh. Eres uno de los usuarios que más valoro y respeto. Ánimo con ese diamante :)

Answer (score 21):

Me gustaría parafrasear a Simon Sinek, gran orador acerca del liderazgo y a mi juicio uno de los mejores en haber dado una charla en TED:

> Ser un líder no se trata de mandar. Ser un líder no es gratis, y muchas veces es muy poco gratificante. Los verdaderos líderes sufren, porque tienen que proteger a los suyos, de sí mismos y de los superiores, a veces incluso inmolándose a sí mismos y siendo los héroes silenciosos que nadie recuerda. La verdadera gratificación del liderazgo viene al ver cómo tus protegidos consiguen superarse a sí mismos y, bajo tu guía, alcanzan todo el potencial de lo que son capaces.

Siento de verdad que no hayamos sido capaces de darte la gratificación que te mereces.

La primera vez que entré al chat de StackOverflow, tenía miedo. Tenía miedo de no encajar en el sitio de fábula donde las grandes mentes intercambiarían ideas, y donde yo no sería más que un novato sin nada que aportar. Y entonces, después de un par de horas de mirar desde las sombras, vi que hiciste un chiste (muy malo, por cierto). **¡Un moderador, haciendo un chiste en el chat de StackOverflow!**, si eso estaba bien recibido, seguramente yo podría encajar un poco ahí... Y de ahí hasta hoy, cuando me he llevado este mazazo.

Siguiendo con las citas:

> Los líderes tienen acceso a las mejores herramientas, y los demás nos apartamos de buena gana, porque cuando los problemas surjan, cuando el depredador esté a la puerta, cuando el departamento de gestión venga a por nosotros, son ellos los que saldrán a defendernos.

Yo no soy moderador y no he tenido acceso a ninguna de las discusiones que los moderadores habréis tenido con nuestros CM. Lo poco que sé es lo que habéis podido y querido contar.

Pero sí sé que tú has moderado con mucha mano izquierda sobre la gente en la que confías, y que cuando han surgido estos problemas, has saltado a defendernos, viendo más allá de cualquier tipo de políticas que se quieran instaurar, y reconociendo en nosotros a personas más allá de los estereotipos. Y para mí eso es algo muy valioso.

He visto cómo en casos en los que a uno le hierve la sangre de ver cómo gente coloca preguntas atroces, de las que te dan ganas de comentar hirientemente hacia estas personas, tú has entrado pacientemente en una conversación con ellos y les has educado en el uso de nuestra plataforma. Creo que yo no tengo esa capacidad, y te respeto por ello.

Y para finalizar:

> En el ejército, se entrena a los soldados para crear líderes, no jefes. No se le puede ordenar a alguien que confíe en ti. Puedes obligarle a guardar las apariencias, pero no puedes cambiar su corazón. Y cuando los peligros surgen, son las lealtades verdaderas, el amor que se profesan estas personas, cuidadosamente nutrido y amparado por sus líderes, la confianza ciega en que, pase lo que pase, tu líder siempre estará cubriéndote las espaldas, y que tu compañero haría lo mismo por ti, lo que hace que estos soldados hagan las locuras que salen en la televisión.

He dejado claro muchas veces que no me gusta nada la dirección que toma StackExchange, y muchas veces me he planteado abandonar la página y esperar pacientemente a que un competidor salga para retomar mi actividad. Me siento traicionado y desechado por *la empresa*. Pero lo que me ha hecho quedarme ha sido la comunidad, **MI** comunidad, a la cual le profeso un profundo cariño y respeto, y de la cual, a mi parecer, tú has sido un líder magnífico.

Antes de ponerme más lacrimógeno, te doy las gracias de corazón por tu tiempo y te pido disculpas porque dejes tu puesto con la sensación de que tu trabajo no ha sido valorado.

Comment: _vi que hiciste un chiste (muy malo, por cierto)_ Era necesaria esa aclaración? Alguna vez @lois6b contó un chiste bueno?

Comment: Maravillosa respuesta.. mil gracias... y si, @Pikoh , si me veis contando un chiste bueno... me han suplantado!

Comment: @Pikoh aquella vez que hizo un trompo con el coche fue... chistosa :)

Answer (score 17):

¿Qué puedo decir que no haya dicho ya David, Pikoh, phpMyGuel... y los que llegarán?

Espero que sigas por aquí y por el chat. Perderte como moderador ya es un palo, pero perderte como compañero habitual en el sitio sería mucho, MUCHO peor.

Comment: Si, seguiré por aqui y por el chat. Muchas gracias, Pablo

Answer (score 16):

Cuando recién entré en el sitio y era un completo novato en la plataforma, fuiste la primera persona en ponerme el famoso [`[Cómo preguntar]` y `[Cómo responder]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/84111/50182).

Lo hiciste con un mensaje claro y conciso, pero le añadiste una frase que ayudaba a seguir mejorando el contenido y seguir aportando en el sitio (cosa que se agradece mucho).

De esta forma es como has moderado el sitio, has dedicado tu tiempo a ayudar a usuarios y has tomado las decisiones que debías con cabeza, nada de lo que no sentirse orgulloso.

Por último te agradezco mucho todo lo que has hecho por el sitio y por todos nosotros y por los ratos que hemos pasado en el chat o similares.

Eres un grande!

Comment: @lois6b tambien me paso lo mismo que a Marc cuando recien llegue era mas facil el bombardeo de puntos negativos que enseñarte las reglas del juego esto sigue pasando pero tus influencias en el chat hicieron que estas acciones bajaran

Answer (score 15):

De un tiempo a esta parte todo son malas noticias en Stack Overflow y la de tu renuncia es una de las grandes. Hace tiempo que habías comunicado que te ponías en *suspenso* y la poca actividad en el sitio hacía pensar que este momento llegaría. No por ello es menos triste...

Has sido moderador dos años y medio, que en internet son como diez veces más, y más en un lugar tan intenso como este. Espero que aún no te hayan salido canas :P

No me prodigo demasiado en el chat, pero cada vez que hemos coincidido ha sido un placer tratarte y ver cómo tratas los temas, además de interesante ver cómo nos ilustrabas con *el libro del día*. Al humor y el buen rollo le sumas el buen hacer y el sentido común ([lo pensaba en su momento](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2324/83) y el tiempo lo ha confirmado). También hemos intercambiado algún email y conversación privada en relación a temas de moderación y siempre he sentido una buena combinación de poner a las personas primero y tener aprecio por la comunidad en su conjunto.

Seguro que un descanso te sienta bien para coger distancia y perspectiva. Mira estos años con cariño y con la satisfacción de haber hecho un gran trabajo para que el sitio sea tan potente. ¡Te has dejado la piel de forma altruista! Ha sido una tarea tan poco reconocida como [necesaria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392922/1983854). Stack Overflow ha llegado a ser lo que es gracias a gente como tú y eso es muy grande.

Un abrazo gigante y nos vemos en los bares :D

Comment: Muchas gracias , Fedorqui. Fuiste uno de mis referentes y cuando me presenté a mod pensé que ojalá fuera tan bueno como tú. En los bares y sidrerías ;)

Comment: @lois6b cuando quieras ;-) Solo tú y tus compañeros moderadores sabéis la de cosas que habéis tenido que gestionar. Desde fuera parece una comunidad bastante tranquila, seguro que es gracias a vuestra labor todo este tiempo. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 14):

Una verdadera lástima, la verdad.

Tan solo agradecerte la labor que has realizado para con el sitio, tanto a nivel profesional (desempeñando tus labores) como a nivel personal y es por esto último por lo que más me apeno (sin desmerecer tu trabajo, el cual es realizado impecablemente).

Espero que tu decisión no sea la precursora de terminar abandonando el sitio y que podamos seguir viéndote por aquí, tanto respondiendo preguntas o haciéndolas como pasándote por el inframundo del chat.

Sin más, espero que disfrutes de la relajación que acompaña el soltar el lastre de la responsabilidades y que esto provoque que vuelvas a sentir este sitio como un lugar donde pasar parte de tu día, aunque los golpes que vienen de arriba a veces no ayuden.

Comment: Gracias, pasiano!

Answer (score 14):

Ha sido un placer compartir contigo la tarea que nos dieron..

No voy a agregar mas cosas a las ya dichas.. has sido una guia enorme..

Siempre te vamos a estar agradecidos.

Answer (score 10):

Traías un punto de vista diferente y nos hacías pensar, tenías siempre en consideración al usuario, y tus acciones estaban siempre justificadas. Se te va a echar de menos como moderador.

Espero seguir viéndote por el sitio y que, si la situación que te ha llevado a esta decisión cambia, vuelvas a unirte al equipo de moderación en un futuro (una vez moderador, siempre moderador).

¡Agur!

Comment: Gracias, Álvaro. Siento que mi marcha fuera tan repentina. Un saludo

Answer (score 9):

Tengo poco que decir<sup>1</sup>.

Que corra la birra.

---

<sup>1</sup>Reportar `->` **Esto es comentario sobre otra publicación, no una respuesta**.

“Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).”

Comment: xDDD  gracias por la birra y el humor

Comment: Es curioso porque el comentario es sobre la misma publicación o más bien la pregunta, no sobre otra.

Comment: Por cierto, recientemente vi que aquí lo discutieron... [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3144)... Yo lo dejaría como **Esto es un comentario, no una respuesta**, sin que importe si es sobre la misma o sobre otra.